# goto different labels depending of value of variable that may be empty or undefined

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I worked with 4DOS a lot decades ago, and bash more recently, but don't have experience with plain Windows batch. I'm trying to make something to conveniently kill the firefox.exe processes that sometimes misfire and never show Firefox but persist and eat my resources.

Trying to make a query-to-user that defaults to kill the processes.
The first problem is the "if %REPLy%==SOMETHING (goto SOMEWHERE)" statements.
The explicit ones work fine but I want to kill the firefoxes if none of them are true. I thought I'd just put the code after the "if...goto"s but that didn't work. So I tried an additional if based on the variable REPLy equaling nothing. That didn't work. So I thought maybe a variable equaling nothing ("") might not be the same as being undeclared and maybe the reply stuff was simply removing the variable rather than giving the value "" and added an if for that. That didn't work either. So I thought maybe I had to put the kill code under a label and send execution there with a goto like the I did in the statements that work, but that doesn't work either. If I enter SOMETHING other than the explicit variations of NO or no, full or truncated, it works, kinda. The taskkill command reports success but it still fails in reality. But I'll work on that bridge when I get there. The immediate problem is how to get NO entry (in other words, just hit the enter key) to goto the kill code just like a non-no string does. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@echo off

REM All this stuff with the path is because I can't reboot this system right now (long story) and I can not seem to make the amended path stick. So for now, I set it each time. I presume I just need to reboot to make the path setting I changed under computer properties, etc, stick.
echo "This is the path:"
path

PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin
echo "This is the path now:"
path
echo "All these path setting and testing commands and remarks can be cleaned up after I figure out if the new path becomes permanent after reboot."
REM Here ends the stuff I expect to delete after I can reboot.

REM Here begins the part I do not expect to change and that works fine.

tasklist | findstr /B firefox.exe | wc -l > kill_firefox.bat_var.tmp

set /p NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs=<kill_firefox.bat_var.tmp
del kill_firefox.bat_var.tmp

IF NOT DEFINED NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs (goto ERROR - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs not set)

if %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs%==0 (goto NO_PROCESSES)

REM Since the contrary conditions lead to gotos, if processing gets to here, there are 1 or more firefox.exe processes.

echo The number of firefox.exe processes running is:
echo .
echo      %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs%
echo .

tasklist | findstr /B firefox.exe

set /p REPLy= "Kill these? Y/n"

echo "REPLy is %REPLy%"
pause

if %REPLy%==n (goto USER DECLINED TO KILL)
if %REPLy%==N (goto USER DECLINED TO KILL)
if %REPLy%==no (goto USER DECLINED TO KILL)
if %REPLy%==NO (goto USER DECLINED TO KILL)

REM Here is where the problems start. By my reasoning, I shouldn't need any if/then here, nor even a goto, just the code that is now in the part labeled KILL. The ifs and the goto and putting the code in the labeled section are the result of many attempts to get that code to run with various constructions.

if [%REPLy%] == [] goto KILL
IF NOT DEFINED REPLy (goto KILL)
goto KILL

:NO_PROCESSES
echo There are no firefox.exe processes running.
pause
exit
:ERROR - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs not set
echo Logic error - The variable is not defined. This script must be repaired.
pause
exit
:USER DECLINED TO KILL
echo User declined to kill processes.
pause
exit

:KILL
REM I am not sure if ANY of this is running because the pause command is not working and the terminal disappears to fast to see. What am I doing wrong here?
echo killing . . .
taskkill /IM firefox.exe
pause
exit
```

Added by edit:
OK, I musta confused my smart pills with my dumb pills. Here is how I fixed the part that I was stuck on:

I changed
    set /p REPLy= "Kill these? Y/n"
to
   set /p REPLy= "Kill these? Y/n" || set REPLy=Y
and that did the trick. I see why that works, but I don't quite see why the ways I tried before don't. Apparently Batch treats variables set (unset? cleared? nulled?) by "set /p somemessage" with just a plain enter key as a response in some way I don't understand. But anyway, I don't have to understand it, just accept it. The construction with the "||" above works. Anyway this was the part of the problem I asked about and it's solved. If I can't get the rest of it working I'll post again after cleaning this batch file up a bit.

Comment: Run the script from the command prompt instead of double clicking it to prevent the terminal from disappearing. Also, spaces are not preserved in label names, so you've got labels called `ERROR` and `USER`. That may cause issues down the line, although it currently works fine since you don't have any other labels starting with those words.

Comment: Thanks. I'll study that. It'll probably help me the rest of it running. I don't see a rep button or anything like that. I need to study the site a bit.

Answer (score 0):

use `setx` to set a permanent variable (see `setx/?`, the syntax is different from `set`).

`set /p` leaves the variable unchanged, if input is empty. So you can predefine a variable:

```
set "REPLy=Y"
set /p "REPLy=Kill these? Y/n"
echo %REPLy%
echo first letter of REPLy is %REPLy:~0,1%
```

but instead of `set /p`, I would use `choice`.

There is no "empty" variable. If it has no value, the variable is not defined.

`if` has a `/i` switch to ignore capitalization.

To get the number of processes I would use (no need for an external utility):

```
for /f %%i in ('tasklist ^| find /c "firefox.exe"') do set NUMBER_OF_PROCESSEs=%%i
```

and as SomethingDark already mentioned:

run the script  from the command prompt instead of double clicking it (and use `exit /b` instead of `exit`)

don't use spaces in labels.